# www to non www on subdomain redirect in URL Rewrite

Tags: iis

I have a webserver that hosts portal.mydomain.com.  I have a working URL Rewrite rule in place to redirect any traffic from http://portal.mydomain.com to go to https://portal.mydomain.com.

Now i am trying to write a rule so that if anyone goes to http://www.portal.mydomain.com OR https://www.portal.mydomain.com to redirect to https://portal.mydomain.com

Right now i just have an external dns record that says [www.portal.mydomain.com](http://www.portal.mydomain.com) is a cname/alias for portal.mydomain.com

This works, but of users get a cert warning.  I want to use url rewrite in IIS to redirect folks so that the cert warning goes away.

Everything i have searched and tried seems to not work.  I think my closest iteration of a rule looks like this, but I need someone to tell me what i am doing wrong.

[image: URL Rewrite Rule Part 1]

[image: URL Rewrite Rule Part 2]

Answer (score 0):

"I want to use url rewrite in IIS to redirect folks so that the cert warning goes away" is impossible.

The certificate error is part of TLS handshake, which happens long before URL rewriting. So your only option to address that certificate issue is to configure a proper certificate for `https://www.portal.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Thank you!  I was not aware of that but that makes sense.